# Audio track from remote mediastream is not playing in <video> tag

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-video

I'm working with webRTC on a project. Everything is connecting and working the first go-round. Both parties receive video/audio appropriately. The audio and video are being recorded on one side of the connection.

I am allowing video and audio muting, as well as screen-share, by calling `replaceTrack()` on the appropriate peer connection senders.

Peer A *(who is recording audio and video from their local stream and remote stream)* switches audio *or* video inputs. The change works perfectly and shows on both Peers.

Peer B terminates the connection.

Peer A then goes into listening mode, waiting for Peer B to come back.

Peer B initiates connection and the connection is made. Peer A can see, hear and record Peer B. Peer B can see Peer A, but not hear them. If Peer A changes an audio source, then Peer B can hear again just fine.

Here's what I cannot figure out: In the lull where Peer B can see but not hear Peer A, the video element for Peer B shows that its source is a mediastream with a live, unmuted, enabled audio track, and alive, unmuted, enabled video track. Here is the log of the audio track:

[image]

Any ideas or thoughts on why the Audio - represented by the log above - would not be playing. Keep in mind, the video is playing just fine at this point. I've already had user gesture here, so that shouldn't come into play.

Comment: Could you show a bit of code? How is the renegociation done? How is its end handled? Is the muted track also stopped? And does this happen in both Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: There's no renegotiation coming into play here. The peer connection is completely ended. For some reason though, when the new connection is established, the video element has a srcObject with an intact video and audio track, non-muted, enabled, with a readyState of live. It plays the video, but isn't playing the audio until the remote peer calls `replaceTrack` on the RTCrtpSender handling audio.

I cannot post any code in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: To add to that, if `replaceTrack` is called in this case, whatever track was in is being stopped before the `replaceTrack(newAudioTrack)` is initiated. The recording mechanism is picking everything up like there's no issue... and both sides are using the same handling code.